# Manipulating an API Feed with Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm a total beginner so I apologize if this question is elementary.

I have a data api that returns a JSON object in this format:

```
{"Variable": "Number", "Variable2": "Number2"}; //(yes the number is returned as a string)
```

I want to create a page where the the values from the the object ("Number" & "Number2") are continuously updated since the values are constantly changing, but the entire page doesn't need to refresh.

http://sendgrid.com has a great example of what I want to do.

Any help would be great!

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I got stuck because I know almost nothing about JS. I have coded a few pages mostly in php.  I figured I could iframe the data and have that part of the page refresh, but I think it would be better in php.

Comment: Well then I suggest that you learn JS first and come back if you still can't get it to work, layout out the specific problems that you are facing. Do not expect us to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to handle data that continuously changes is by using setTimeout. There is another method called setInterval, but it is better to use setTimeout with a recursive function. That way if the operation takes longer than expected, the timer won't be out of sync. Demonstrated through example:

```
function updateCounter() {
 var timer; 

 document.getElementById("counter").innerText(data.Variable);

 timer = setTimeout(updateCounter, 50);

}
```

Comment: +1 That is how to avoid setInterval, was about to write the same.

Comment: Of course, one would want to save the element #counter outside of the loop for a performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can send request to your api using `setInterval()` and update you target elements with your data.

***Just an example:***

```
function updater() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'src_to_script',
    dataType: 'json',
    sucess: function(data) {

       // updating your target elements
       $('#some_item1').text( data.Variable);
       $('#some_item2').text( data.Variable2);

       // call updater with 5 seconds interval
       setInterval(updater, 5000);

    }
  });
}

// initial call to updater
updater();
```